# radeon power management

Tags: linux, radeon

Checking upon `/sys/kernel/debug/dri/0/radeon_pm_info`, puzzled me. It seems that there are only one power level and some are disabled.
It shows :

```
uvd    disabled
vce    disabled
power level 0    sclk: 30000 vddc: 3800
```

Why are they disabled and there are only one power level?

**Background**

I'm using a laptop with AMD A6-6310 APU with AMD Radeon R4 Graphics with the default open source `radeon` kernel module. Compared to the `fglrx` module, the battery usage is about 6 mW, as reported by powertop, but when the `radeon` kernel module was used in the same scenario, the battery usage is 11mW. I tried setting these and it did not change much :

```
 echo low > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_dpm_force_performance_level
 echo battery > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_dpm_state.
```

Answer (score 0):

to clear the misconception on the output of `radeon_pm_info` (or `amdgpu_pm_info`):

`uvd` and `vce` do not refer to power levels, but are video decoding and encoding functions. To quote Alex Deucher from [freedesktop#99513](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=99513#c3)

> UVD and VCE get disabled at runtime to save power.  If you run a video decode or encode task, they will get enabled dynamically.

nowadays, the command will output available clock modes and the current usage. The commands to force lower clocks are proper